# How to get a particular users' email conversation in imap by passing 'to' in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, imap

I need help in how to get the email conversation of a particular email.
Like to pass in 'to' field and get the email conversation of the user and the passed email address.

I currently have the solution for getting emails for the labels.

```
    var Imap = require(‘imap’),
    inspect = require(‘util’).inspect;
    var fs = require(‘fs’), fileStream;

    var imap = new Imap({
    user: ‘your_email@service.com’,
    password: ‘yourPassword’,
    host: ‘imap.gmail.com’,
    port: 993,
    tls: true
    });

    function openInbox(cb) {
    imap.openBox(‘INBOX’, true, cb);
      }

    imap.once(‘ready’, function() {
    openInbox(function(err, box) {
    if (err) throw err;
    imap.search([ ‘UNSEEN’, [‘SINCE’, ‘June 15, 2018’] ], function(err, results) 
    {
    if (err) throw err;

    var f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: ‘’ });

    f.on(‘message’, function(msg, seqno) {
    console.log(‘Message #%d’, seqno);

    var prefix = ‘(#’ + seqno + ‘) ‘;

    msg.on(‘body’, function(stream, info) {
    console.log(prefix + ‘Body’);
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(‘msg-’ + seqno + ‘-body.txt’));
    });

    msg.once(‘attributes’, function(attrs) {
    console.log(prefix + ‘Attributes: %s’, inspect(attrs, false, 8));
    });

    msg.once(‘end’, function() {
    console.log(prefix + ‘Finished’);
    });

    });
    f.once(‘error’, function(err) {
    console.log(‘Fetch error: ‘ + err);
    });

    f.once(‘end’, function() {
    console.log(‘Done fetching all messages!’);
    imap.end();});

        });
      });
    });
    imap.once(‘error’, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    });

    imap.once(‘end’, function() {
    console.log(‘Connection ended’);
    });
    imap.connect();
```

I expect the code to accept 'to' field and display the whole conversation.
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in code.

Comment: And please post properly indented code, it's impossible to read code like this.

Comment: Since this is for gmail, you can access the message's thread id and then search for messages with the same thread-id. [Here are other questions that mention gmail's thread-id](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=x-gmail-thrid).